# How do I gain more space on the root filesystem?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have multiple filesystems and mounts on a linux device (its an Odroid XU4 with Ubuntu OS) im using. I'm using an SD Card for booting, which is 64gb, and there is an emmc module also attached, which is 64gb.

Problem is, I can't install any packages now or create new files/directories as my root filesystem is full. However, I know there is 100GB or more available still, I just don't think I'm utilizing the space properly on the SD and EMMC.

Here is the output I get from df -h

```
odroid@odroid:~$ df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           209M   25M  185M  12% /run
/dev/mmcblk1p3  7.3G  7.2G     0 100% /
tmpfs           1.1G     0  1.1G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
/dev/mmcblk0p1  134M   19M  116M  14% /media/boot
tmpfs           209M  164k  209M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/mmcblk1p1  134M   17M  118M  13% /media/odroid/boot
/dev/mmcblk0p2  5.2G  4.0G  1.2G  78% /home/odroid/disk
/dev/mmcblk1p3   56G   66k   56G   1% /mnt
```

I understand the above as saying that I have an additional filesystem, which I can access under /mnt, that has 56GB of space available. However, whenever I run apt-get or try to create new files, it says I have zero space. How can I make use of this /mnt mount for all additional storage allocating tasks I'll be doing?

And here is the output from df -I:

```
odroid@odroid:~$ sudo df -i
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
tmpfs          187999   1844 186155    1% /run
/dev/mmcblk1p3 450560 247441 203119   55% /
tmpfs          187999      1 187998    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          187999      4 187995    1% /run/lock
/dev/mmcblk0p1      0      0      0     - /media/boot
tmpfs           51004    139  50865    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/mmcblk1p1      0      0      0     - /media/odroid/boot
/dev/mmcblk0p2 327680 169130 158550   52% /home/odroid/disk
/dev/mmcblk1p3      0      0      0     - /mnt
```

Fdisk -l output for the commenters below

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 58.24 GiB, 62537072640 bytes, 122142720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3cedfd53

Device         Boot    Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk1p1          2048    264191    262144  128M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk1p2        264192  14600191  14336000  6.8G 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk1p3      14600192 122142719 107542528 51.3G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 58.24 GiB, 62537072640 bytes, 122142720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3cedfd53

Device         Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        2048    264191    262144  128M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      264192 122140672 121876481 58.1G 83 Linux
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please shot the output of `fdisk -l`.

Comment: First, don't use `sudo` where it is not required, as in `df -i`. We do need your partition table to see if there is space for `/dev/mmcblk1p3` to be expanded to the end of the disk or if partition 2 even exists.

Comment: Please check your copy-and-paste as you have two `mmcblk1p3` devices listed, and that shouldn't be possible

Comment: Hi Roaima, I definitely have the correct copy and pasta. Just verified. There is two mmcblk1p3 devices.

Comment: Fdisk -l returned a lot of input. So I'll skip the ram[number] portion and show you the parts that I think you guys would find most relevant? Let me know. I've edited the original post at the bottom to add the fdisk output.

Comment: `How can I make use of this /mnt mount for all additional storage allocating tasks I'll be doing?` You pretty much can't. You'll need to shrink the filesystem **and** partition that you don't need that much space from and extend the ones that do with the space. You'll need to move the shrunk partition so that the space will be LBA-wise at the end of the one that need to be extended. FAT32 is hard to shrink (the only tool is somewhat bugged) so I suggest you to do a back and forth transfer (of files) instead anyway.

Comment: In the future, you probably want to deploy LVM or so.

Comment: Is there no way for me to redirect basically every action on Linux that requires space, to a different file system (one with space), rather than the root file system? IE: when I run yum install for any package, it says I have no space. How can I redirect all of those sort of actions to a new file system automatically?

Comment: No, there is not.